# Spring MVC DeferredResult Async Request not work, async requests response immediately

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous

Controller

```
package farm.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResult;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/def")
public class DeferredController {

    DeferredResult<String> defReq;


    @RequestMapping("/fasen")
    @ResponseBody
    public DeferredResult<String> fasen() {
        defReq = new DeferredResult<String>(null,"timeout response");
        defReq.onCompletion(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("after deferredResult completion ...");

            }
        });
        return defReq;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/loose")
    public @ResponseBody String loose() {
        if(defReq!=null) {
            defReq.setResult("loose Result");
            defReq = null;
            return "loose success";
        } else {
            return "loose not needed";
        }

    }

}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <display-name>testfarm</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring.xml,classpath:spring-mybatis.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>utf-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- 防止spring内存溢出监听器 -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.IntrospectorCleanupListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <description>spring mvc servlet</description>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                classpath:spring-mvc.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htmls</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <!-- 配置session超时时间，单位分钟 -->
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

console output when I explore url:http://localhost:8080/master/do/rest/hasMsg.htmls

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'rest' processing GET request for [/def/fasen.htmls]
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Matching patterns for request [/def/fasen.htmls] are [/def/fasen.*]
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - URI Template variables for request [/def/fasen.htmls] are {}
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapping [/def/fasen.htmls] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [farm.controller.DeferredController@ab2d774] and 1 interceptor
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/def/fasen.htmls] is: -1
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker - Invoking request handler method: public org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResult farm.controller.DeferredController.fasen()
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter - Written [org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResult@420d10a7] as "text/html" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@5168759b]
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'rest': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

When I send a http request, the response result immediately returns within a second, I don't know whether I got error configuration, and I have spend a whole day dealing with it.

Comment: nothing in your code looks like it would take a significant amount of time, have you tried adding Thread.sleep?

Comment: What behavior do you expect and why?

Comment: I found the reason after long time.  It is I config
`<bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
  <property name="order" value="0" />
 </bean>`
in my spring applicationContext.xml.

Answer (score 0):

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="order" value="0" />
</bean>
```

shouldn't be configured in applicationContext.xml. In Spring MVC official docs, the reason is described like this:

```
    Prior to Spring 3.1, type and method-level request mappings were examined 
in two separate stages — a controller was selected first by the DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping 
and the actual method to invoke was narrowed down second by the AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.

    With the new support classes in Spring 3.1, the RequestMappingHandlerMapping is the 
only place where a decision is made about which method should process the request.
Think of controller methods as a collection of unique endpoints with mappings for 
each method derived from type and method-level @RequestMapping information.
```